# Removing NaN from calculation

Tags: jquery

```
$('.field-name-field-weight-1 input').change(function(){
    var wt1 = $(this).val();
    var the = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    var wt2 = the.find('.field-name-field-weight-2 input').val();
    var total = parseFloat(wt1) - parseFloat(wt2);
    var result = the.find('.field-name-field-weight-3 input').val(total.toFixed(2));
});

$('.field-name-field-weight-2 input').change(function(){
    var wt2 = $(this).val();
    var the = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    var wt1 = the.find('.field-name-field-weight-1 input').val();
    var total = parseFloat(wt1) - parseFloat(wt2);
    var result = the.find('.field-name-field-weight-3 input').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
}
};
})(jQuery);
```

I have this piece of code. I want to get rid of `NaN`. 
Basically, when i enter a number into weight-1 field it shows `NaN` into `weight-3` field. I want to get rid of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of `parent().parent().parent().parent()` you can use `parents()` or `closest()` and provide a selector

Comment: `total.toFixed(2)` why do you want it to be a string ?

Comment: I want the result upto 2 decimal points, so I have put that

Answer (score 1):

Just test for `NaN`:

```
if (!isNaN(total)) {
    // Put it in the field...
}
```

Better yet, catch the `NaN` result earlier in the calculation (just after doing `parseFloat` on `wt1` and `wt2`), and point out the relevant invalid field value to the user.

---

Re your comment:

> I cant see anything than in the result field if I put the above

If you always want to update the result, even when you have invalid inputs, just use an `else` and fill in whatever you want the result to be when the inputs are invalid. Or you can use the ternary operator:

```
var result = the.find('.field-name-field-weight-3 input').val(
    isNaN(total) ? '' : total.toFixed(2)
);
```

That will set the result field to blank when the inputs are invalid. But again, I'd catch which input was invalid and let the user know.

Comment: I cant see anything than in the result field if I put the above

Comment: I tried to put this, now it doesnt show me NaN. But if i change the input in weight-1 or weight-2 field it doesnt show me the appropriate result .                                                     var total = parseFloat(grosswt).val()||"0" - parseFloat(tarewt).val()||"0";

Comment: @soniajain: Then just put an `else` clause on and put whatever it is you want in the result field when the inputs are invalid there. The point is that the inputs cannot be parsed as numbers, so you have no result.